# UILabel subclass appearance in Storyboard

Tags: swift, uikit, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I have created a subclass of UILabel called MyUILabel. The only thing changed is the font and font-size. It appears as expected when I run the app. However, the in the Storyboard, the default UILabel is showed. Is there any way to make Storyboards show the font and font-size from my subclass?

MyUILabel:

```
public class MyUILabel : UILabel {
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.font = UIFont(name: Constants.DefaultFont, size: 30)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make it `@IBDesignable`, and then implement `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`:

```
@IBDesignable
public class MyUILabel: UILabel {

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureLabel()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        configureLabel()
    }

    func configureLabel() {
        font = UIFont(name: Constants.DefaultFont, size: 40)
    }

}
```

Note, IB didn't like it when I implemented `init(coder:)`, so I moved it into `awakeFromNib`.

Also note that when you make an `@IBDesignable` class, Apple advises that you create a separate target (e.g. "File" - "New" - "Target..." - "Cocoa Touch Framework") for this designable class. For more information, see WWDC 2014 video [What’s New in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/411/).

Comment: Super! Thanks! Hope your answer will help someone else as well.

Comment: Thanks it works, but if it possible to change the default font in Attributes inspector?